# Delete a data from DB on selection of Delete operation in SweetAlert popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sweetalert

```
{ data: null, "render": function (data, type, full, row) { return '<a href="/EmployeeManagement/DeleteEmployee/' + full.userId + '" onClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: red; text-decoration:unset;"></span></a>'; }, "autoWidth": false, "searchable": false, "sortable": false, "width": "7%"}

var object = { status: false, ele: null };
    function ConfirmDelete(event) {
        if (object.status) { return true; }
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            closeOnConfirm: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                )
            }
        }),
            function() {
                object.status = true;
                object.ele = event;

                object.ele.click();
            };
        return false;
};
```

I have written this code to display sweetalert popup on delete operation, But when I tried to click on "Yes, Delete it!" it does not delete the data. What changes are required to correct this?

Comment: I am not seeing code for delete here .. you are only showing `Swal.fire('Deleted!'..` ?

Comment: Yes , I have written the method to delete a record and it works fine but issue here is when I select "Yes, Delete it!" button in sweetalert popup record is not deleted.

Comment: Can any one help me to solve this?